# Mazda Axela Hatchback has slow pick-up

Tags: transmission, mazda

Hie I resently bought a second hand Mazda axela 2004 problem seems to be a very slow pick up speed from a complete stop. This also appears to happen when on the road and i hit the brakes a bit and try to persay overtake a car, its absolutely humiliatingly slow. Sometimes have to shift into the tiptronic manual side and drop the gears and hope it breathes in some air to blow up some speed. Ive done basic service on the vehicle, new oil, spark plugs, air and oil filters. But what could explain this sluggish movement and the fuel consumption is high.... from the foot being hard on the pedal and no to slow significant changes in speed. Please help!!! Ive done some research and im suspecting either my catalytic convertor or gearbox is in some way damaged. Dont want to make any rash decisions without more advice.

Comment: If you suspect the cat is partially plugged pull the b1s1 o2 sensor and see if it helps. any lights on the instrument cluster?

Comment: Have you checked the fuel filter?